# Switching between UITableViewController and UIViewController with table view inside

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to transition from a UITableViewController to a UIViewController with a UITableView within it.

In my HomeViewController, I changed it from

```
HomeViewController: UITableViewController
```

to

```
HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
```

Now in storyboard, when I drag a Table View onto the View Controller, the TableView automatically resizes to the full screen... I made a reference to tableView in the Controller and set

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.datasource = self
```

but in HomeViewController when I print (self.view is UITableView) it prints true. When I tried to delete the TableView from the HomeVC in storyboard, and add a UIView instead, it wouldnt let me. I am confused why?  How can I transition from TableView to TableView within UIViewController.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, in your strorybord you have built in `UITableViewController` that Manages a `UITableView` and its custom class should a subclass of `UITableViewController`. so the change you made to you custom class to a subclass of `UIViewController` will not work as you expected.

You need to drag a `UIViewController` then add UITableView as any view. then set custom class the one you have.

Also: .h

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController 
//...
@end
```

.m

```
@interface HomeViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> //implement Protocol
//...
@end
```